# Extracting a specific value from a text file

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I am running a script that outputs data.

I am specifically trying to extract one number. However, each time I run the script and get the output file, the position of the number I am interested in will be in a different position (due to the log nature of the output file).

I have tried several awk, sed, grep commands but I can't get any to work as many of them rely on the position of the word or number remaining constant.

This is what I am dealing, with. The value I require is the **bold** one:

Energy initial, next-to-last, final = 
        -5.96306582435     -5.96306582435     **-5.96349956298**

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow, please post sample Inputs with code tags and expected output in code tags as it is not clear.

Comment: Why can't you use grep with regex? Please post the command that you've tried.

Comment: There is no "starred one".. You have to tell us WHY a given number is expected to be output - based on it's position, based on it's position relative to some other number, based on a header field, based on a value or something else?

Comment: Can u post some sample input and output...

Comment: @EdMorton - the starred one is the last one (I guess) as it's been italicised by SO syntax

Comment: As requested in  the first comment you got, [edit] your code, sample input, and expected output to use the editors `{}` button to format it correctly. Don't add stars to your sample data if they aren't present in your real data.

Comment: Also, you still haven;t told us WHY that value should be output.

Comment: If the position is changing how do you identify the number.  In another words, if it wasn't bold how would you describe it.  e.g. The last in position after keyword *Energy initial*?

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
awk '{print $(i++%3+6)}' infile
```